# autofocus in laravel cursor point automically in input user can type please answer in product_name textbox

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

```
 autofocus not work in  laravel page 
Just passed with array() or in javascript I also tried please help me
```

{!! Form::open(['url' => action('ProductController@saveQuickProduct'), 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'quick_add_product_form' ]) !!}

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">@lang( 'product.add_new_product' )</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        
        {!! Form::label('name', __('product.product_name') . ':*') !!}
        
          {!! Form::text('c', null,array('autofocus'=>'autofocus'),['class' =>'form-control', 'required', 
          'placeholder' => __('product.product_name')]); !!} 
          {!! Form::select('type', ['single' => 'Single', 'variable' => 'Variable'], 'single', ['class' => 'hide', 'id' => 'type']); !!}
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
user can type without click on textbox
```

Comment: Would you mind asking what you want clearly and formatting your code correctly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.